# SQL Server returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." in Windows application

Tags: sql-server, security, sqlconnection

An application that has been working without problem (and has not had any active development done on it in about 6 months or so) recently began failing to connect to database.  Operations admins cant say what might have changed that would cause the problem.

The client application uses a hardcoded connection string with Integrated Security=True, but when the applications attempts to create a connection to the database, it throws an SQLException saying "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON".

I can log on to the database through Management Studio on this account without problem.  All of the things that I have seen for this issue are for ASP.NET projects and it is apparently the "Double Hop Problem" which being a client application darned well better not be a problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit

The client machine and server machine as well as user accounts are on the same domain.
This occurs when Windows Firewall is off.

Leading theory is:
Server was restarted about a week or so ago, and failed to register Service Principal Name (SPN).  Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If your issue is with linked servers, you need to look at a few things.

First, your users need to have delegation enabled and if the only thing that's changed, it'l likely they do. Otherwise you can uncheck the "Account is sensitive and cannot be delegated" checkbox is the user properties in AD.

Second, your service account(s) must be trusted for delegation. Since you recently changed your service account I suspect this is the culprit. ([http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739474(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739474%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

You mentioned that you might have some SPN issues, so be sure to set the SPN for both endpoints, otherwise you will not be able to see the delegation tab in AD. Also make sure you're in advanced view in "Active Directory Users and Computers."

If you still do not see the delegation tab, even after correcting your SPN, make sure your domain not in 2000 mode. If it is, you can "raise domain function level."

At this point, you can now mark the account as trusted for delegation:

> In the details pane, right-click the user you want to be trusted for
>   delegation, and click Properties.
>
> Click the Delegation tab, select the Account is trusted for delegation
>   check box, and then click OK.

Finally you will also need to set all the machines as trusted for delegation.

Once you've done this, reconnect to your sql server and test your liked servers. They should work.

Comment: Nice answer.  I've linked back to this one from a more recent question here, where scenario is different, but symptom and root cause are the same:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47871816/how-to-run-an-r-script-which-has-database-connection-using-integrated-windows-a/47877987#47877987

Comment: A special up vote for the delegation configuration on the computer device itself (not just on the service account). Most other posts have left this out.

Answer (score 10):

First off: My problem isn't the exact same as yours, but this post is the first thing that comes up in google for the `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` error at the time I wrote this. The solution may be useful to people searching for this error as I did not find this specific solution anywhere online.

In my case, I used Xampp/Apache and PHP sqlsrv to try to connect to an MSSQL database using Windows Authentication and received the `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` error you described. I finally found the problem to be the Apache service itself running under the user "LOCAL SERVICE" instead of the user account I was logged in as. In other words, it literally was using an anonymous account. The solution was to go into services.msc, right click the Apache service, go to Properties, go to the Log On tab, and enter the credentials for the user. This falls in line with your problem related to SPN's as your SPN's are set up to run from a specific user on the domain. So if the correct SPN is not running, windows authentication will default to the wrong user (likely the "LOCAL SERVICE" user) and give you the Anonymous error.

Here's where it's different from your problem. None of the computers on the local network are on a Domain, they are only on a Workgroup. To use Windows Authentication with a Workgroup, both the computer with the server (in my case MSSQL Server) and the computer with the service requesting data (in my case Apache) needed to have a user with an identical name and identical password.

To summarize, The `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` error in both our cases seems to be caused by a service not running and/or not on the right user. Ensuring the right SPN or other Service is running and under the correct user should solve the anonymous part of the problem.

Comment: I already had the question answered, so I thought it would be helpful for people searching in google. Many other forums had posts with similar problems linking to this article getting mixed responses about whether or not it actually helped, so I was trying to help address them, i.e. adding related information and possible solutions rather than requesting help.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it led me to figure out why an installer was failing with this error (a custom action was trying to connect to SQL, and custom actions run under SYSTEM by default for VS installers).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caboosetp ! I was having trouble connecting to an MSSQL DB and you solved it.

Answer (score 6):

I think there must have been some change in AD group used to authenticate against the database. Add the web server name, in the format domain\webservername$, to the AD group that had access to the database. In addition, also try to set the web.config  attribute to "false". Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: Going by what you have edited.. it most probably indicate that the authentication protocol of your SQL Server has fallen back from Kerberos(Default, if you were using Windows integrated authentication) to NTLM. For using Kerberos service principal name (SPN) must be registered in the Active Directory directory service. Service Principal Name(SPNs) are unique identifiers for services running on servers. Each service  that will use Kerberos authentication needs to have an SPN set for it so that clients can identify the service on the network. It is registered in Active Directory under either a computer account or a user account. Although the Kerberos protocol is the default, if the default fails, authentication process will be tried using NTLM.

In your scenario, client must be making tcp connection, and it is most likely running under LocalSystem account, and there is no SPN registered for SQL instance, hence, NTLM is used, however, LocalSystem account inherits from System Context instead of a true user-based context, thus, failed as 'ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

To resolve this ask your domain administrator to manually register SPN if your SQL Server running under a domain user account.
Following links might help you more:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/12/479871.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909801

Comment: Actually, after a bit more digging, it looks like it is a linked server problem.  We had some personnel changes and the servers accounts where changed for security purposes.  The client applications first order of business is querying a view with links to all of the other servers.  Running that query in Management studio results in the same error message.  We are fiddling around with the links now.

Answer (score 5):

You probably just need to provide a user name and password in your connectionstring and set Integrated Security=false

Comment: See above, the accepted answer.  The issue was with Linked Servers and SPNs.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting "Integrated Security=False" in the connection string.

```
<add name="YourContext" connectionString="Data Source=<IPAddressOfDBServer>;Initial Catalog=<DBName>;USER ID=<youruserid>;Password=<yourpassword>;Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of my SQL jobs had the same issue. It involved uploadaing data from one server to another. The error occurred because I was using sql Server Agent Service Account. I created a Credential using a UserId (that uses Window authentication) common to all servers. Then created a Proxy using this credential. Used the proxy in sql server job and it is running fine.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, in our case a (PHP) website running on IIS was showing this message on attempting to connect to a database.

The resolution was to edit the Anonymous Authentication on that website to use the Application pool identity (and we set the application pool entry up to use a service account designed for that website).

Comment: This also can happen in IIS. _IIS Manager, select the application, double-click its Authentication icon, click the Edit link, select the Application Pool Identity radio button in the edit modal, click okay, profit._

Answer (score 1):

**A similar case solved:**

In our case, we wanted to set up linked servers using cnames and with the logins current security context.

All in order we checked that the service account running SQL Server had its' proper spns set and that the AD-object was trusted for delegation. But, while we were able to connect to the cname directly, we still had issues calling a linked server on its' cname: `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`

It took us far too long to realize that the cnames we used was for A-record, [A], that was set on a higher dns level, and not in its' own domain AD-level. Originally, we had the cname directing to [A].example.com and not (where it should) to: [A].domain.ad.example.com

Ofcourse we had these errors about anonymous logon.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to app pool select Process model in Advance Setting then select Identity  and in identity set your account details like username and password of your system.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I created SQL Server User like "sa" in secure store. Use the "sa" credential while creating the external content type. It solved the issue. Before this I was using Windows authentication that is service account like domain\spsetup.

Please note my SQL Server for SharePoint was configured for both SQL and Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are connected to ServerA, but when running your queries in ServerA, your credentials are not passed to ServerB where you have the tables.

If you are facing this error in Linked Server, below are the steps I used to resolve this issue. Hope this will be useful for everyone.

1. Login/RDP(Remote Desktop Protocol) to the computer/VM where the SQL Server is running using your Authentication.
2. Login to SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio)
3. Go to Server Objects / Linked Server and select the Linked server and try 'Test Connect'.

Now you should be able to connect to the Linked Server without the above-mentioned error.

Answer (score -1):

Got it!  Solved the issue modifying the user properties in security session of SQL Server. In SQL Server Management, go into security -> Logon -> Choose the user used for DB connection and go into his properties. Go to "Securators" tab and look for line "Connect SQL", mark "Grant" option and take a try. It works for me!

Regards