# NT Authority\Anonymous Logon throws connecting through WMI Connection from Web Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, wmi, exe

I have Web,APP,DB Server
App Server which has a Exe it will do some operation .
**when I am trying to Trigger a Exe which is in App Server through WMI Connection from Webserver  please refer below code**

```
     public void RunProcessOnRemoteMachine(string inputFolder, string ProcessName, string AppRun, string isRegression, string TemplateID, string isPreProcess, string UserLoginName, string DocYear,string remoteMachine,string strPathToTheExe)
    {
        string usernameAndDomain = "";
        string password = "";
        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            if (Environment.MachineName.ToUpper() != remoteMachine.ToUpper())
            {

            }
            ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", remoteMachine), connOptions);
            manScope.Connect();
             ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            inParams["CommandLine"] = strPathToTheExe + " " + "\"" + inputFolder + "\" \"" + ProcessName + "\" \"" + AppRun + "\" \"" + isRegression + "\" \"" + TemplateID + "\" \"" + isPreProcess + "\" \"" + UserLoginName + "\" \"" + DocYear+"\""; 
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null );
                Cls_ErrorLog.Writelog("Creation of the process returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
            Cls_ErrorLog.Writelog("Process ID: " + outParams["processId"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Cls_ErrorLog.Writelog("Exception occured in method RunProcessOnRemoteMachine : " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
```

I set Integrated Security=True in my Exe Config and Web config and also i added that user in Sql Server Logins and gave the rights.

After made a Connection that EXe is Running with same Credential(what we set in Identity in IIS) in Appserver  But it could not connect a database connection with same credentials

it throws **Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON**. but when we track the exe which is running with same credentials

when we run a Exe manually in App Server its works

So Please Suggest a Solutions 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to parametrise that query. `"where ServerName='" + remoteMachine + "'"` is wide open to injection.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your reply. Yes thats ok but I am having problem while connecting the database. no issue in connecting server using wmi method

Comment: when i try to run the exe from command prompt works fine. The problem running the exe as background from wmi method its trying to connect database with   'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' not with login credential when we specify integrated Security is true

Comment: The problem I'm talking about there isn't the connection, it's the SQL. Imagine what would happen if someone passed `'; DROP TABLE CMR_Serverdetails; CREATE LOGIN TestLogin WITH PASSWORD = ''test'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF;--` for the value of `remoteMachine`. Injection is not your friend and you *need* to parametrise your queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." in Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462674/sql-server-returns-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean No Its not Duplicate because I am trying to connect a Server and trigger exe  from Web Server through WMI Connection