# Connection SQL Server 2012 via Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2012, windows-services

I created a windows service for monitoring to send data (OS info, proc, ram etc) to my SQL Server database and it works fine on my computer. I already installed the service in another machine that has SQL Server and it can connect to mydatabase successfully but when the service runs it appear those error in service log.

This is my connection string

```
CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=*******\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Parc_informatique; User Id=tsi;password=******;";
```

Also the service run as local user

> 2020-07-22 15:09:34.7392 - DEBUG: Starting service
> 2020-07-22 15:09:34.7392 - DEBUG: Callback started
> 2020-07-22 15:09:34.7392 - DEBUG: Starting sending Data
> 2020-07-22 15:09:35.1712 - ERROR: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur '**AUTORITE NT\ANONYMOUS LOGON**'.
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> at SignalRbus.InfoManager.SendData() in C:\Users\Rayen\source\repos\project\SignalRbus\SystemInfo.cs:line 197
> at DetailService.Service1.serviceTimer_callback(Object state) in C:\Users\Rayen\source\repos\project\DetailService\Service1.cs:line 45
> ClientConnectionId:a19ffe41-1f72-4e44-a883-f4eed400e93e
> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
> ClientConnectionId :00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
> Error Number :-1,State :0,Class :20

Comment: You should either run the service as a user who has access to your SQL database and use a connection string with a trusted connection. Or you should update your connection string with a username and password that has access to your database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server returns error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'." in Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462674/sql-server-returns-error-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon)

Comment: I have a connection string with username , password  and ,I can connect to my database through SQl server management in the other machine but the service doesn't work and that what I find in log of the windows service

Comment: CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=*\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Parc_informatique; User Id=tsi;password=;Integrated Security=False;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding **Integrated Security=False** to the connection string like this

```
CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=*\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Parc_informatique; User Id=tsi;password=;Integrated Security=False;"
```